# Storing Date in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Seem to be having some issues storing the current date in a core data field...

Here is the code...

```
NSDate *today= [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"the current date is %@",today);

[review setDate:today];

NSLog(@"Date %@", review.date);
```

Here is the log...

```
2012-03-26 23:24:39.187 Review Writer[17813:fb03] the current date is 2012-03-26 22:24:39 +0000
2012-03-26 23:24:39.188 Review Writer[17813:fb03] Date (null)
```

Here is the declaration...

```
@interface Review : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;

@end
```

Comment: `review` is nil. If you try to get an object-property of an “object” which is `nil`, you will get `nil` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you declare review?

The most likely culprit is that review has not been set to an actual instance of Review and is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate:

You need

```
Review *review = [ NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Review" inManagedObjectContext:someContext ];
```

assuming you have an NSManagedObjectModel with an entity named Review.